# Material table onBulkUpdate click don't change icons

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I'm using "material-table": "^2.0.3" version. I want to editable all my data and I used [onBulkUpdate](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable) option in material table document. but after I click the icon next to the search form change to editable but icon doesn't change at all and to give me submit or reject actions to call any function and save my changes.

here is my code:

```
const [columns, setColumns] = useState([
    { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
    {
      title: 'Surname',
      field: 'surname',
    },
    { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear' },
    {
      title: 'Birth Place',
      field: 'birthCity',
      lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' },
    },
  ]);
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
    { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
  ]);

return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <MaterialTable
        title='Bulk Edit Preview'
        columns={columns}
        data={data}
        editable={{
          onBulkUpdate: (changes) =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                resolve();
              }, 1000);
            }),
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by change my package version.

in package.json

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
"material-table": "^1.69.3"
```